# network connection failure after resume from standby 16.04

Tags: networking, suspend

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on a zotac barebone. Network connection via ethernet cable.
This works fine and stable when freshly booted.

However, when the computer resumes from standby, network connection does not work any more: The icon in the upper right corner informing about the network status shows the circle segment either empty or radiating, the  mouseover-information reads "disconnected".
I disabled dhcp and entered ip-address etc. manually, but this did not help: the only difference is that now after resume from standby, the network symbol shows the up and down arrows, and text reads "connected". However, there is no connection, no data transfer.

It might be related to the problem other people had with their laptops, with wifi failure after hibernation. However, I couldn't find any solution to this problem either.
Can anybody help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with Suspend/Resume on my laptop that involved many head scratching moments. But I didn't have your problem with systemd not shutting down network manager on sleep and restarting it on wake. I did some digging and *I think* this is the file you should have on your system.

At the terminal look at the contents of this file by typing: **cat /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        pre) /sbin/wpa_cli suspend ;;
        post) /sbin/wpa_cli resume ;;
    esac
fi
```

If for some reason your file is different or doesn't exist then make it so (Sorry Captain Picarde).

If the file correctly exists on your system then after resuming try typing:

`sudo wpa_cli resume`

and see if that establishes the connection. If it does then there are various bug reports to read such as: [WiFi fails to resume after
suspend; Race with wpasupplicant / wpa_cli resume?](http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2016-06/msg00589.html) This link has links to other bug reports which should keep you busy for awhile.

Comment: I have similar problem, but for Ethernet, not Wifi